# Insert multiple filepaths with sql from folder

Tags: sql, filepath

So I have a folder full of images, and I would like to insert each filepath into a row in one of the tables into my database. Each of them is named from 001.png up to 999.png.

I'm not sure how to do it. I've tried to use a LOOP but my SQL knowledge is basic at best.

It's a single insert, so I don't mind if it takes a while.

Thanks in advance, really appreciate it.

Comment: can you use excel? (to generate the query only) i often use excel to generate one off sets of statements like this.. probably get show for it around here ;) - if column a had 0-999 in it the foluma in b would be something like: `="insert into table (column) values ('/images/"&A1&".png')"`

Comment: *shot not show sorry ;)

Comment: cool.. seeing as its what you went with i posted it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use excel? (to generate the query only)

I often use excel to generate one off sets of statements like this.. probably get shot for it around here ;)

If column A had 0-999 in it the formula in B1 would be something like:

```
="insert into table (column) values ('/images/"&A1&".png')"
```

Then just drag down as normal

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about mySQL but this would work in MSSQL:

```
create table #temp (fname varchar(10))
declare @filename as int
set @filename = 0
WHILE @filename < 1000
BEGIN
    insert into #temp values (right('000' + cast(@filename as varchar(3)),3)+'.png')
    set @filename = @filename + 1
END
select * from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basic structure for inserting image from folder to database in php.

```
$image_types = array(

    'gif' => 'image/gif',

    'png' => 'image/png',

    'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',

);


for ($entry in scandir('images')) {

    if (!is_dir($entry)) {

        if (in_array(mime_content_type('images/'. $entry), $image_types)) {

            // do something with image

        }

    }

}
```